# Using MySQL database with Entity Framework in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I'm trying to set up a web API that accesses a MySQL database using Entity Framework.  To do this, I have downloaded [this connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.8.html).  However, I am unable to figure out how to get this working.  When I create the ADO .NET Entity Data Model, it asks for a source, but all options are Microsoft SQL Server.  If someone could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Edited to add additional information below:

I'm trying to follow the instructions listed [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/426790/Using-MySQL-with-Entity-Framework).  My problem is that even thoguh I have downloaded the connector, I do not see a MySQL database as a possible connection type.  I'm confused as to why this could be and what steps i could take to resolve the problem.

What should appear:
[image]

What I have on my screen:
[image]

Comment: The problem is I am using an Express edition, which apparently doesn't do anything but Microsoft SQL Server by design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install latest MySql Connector.
Following link will help you.

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=395665

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

I installed mysql for visual studio, later mysql connector net and works fine!

mysql to vs:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=458484

mysql connector net
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Regards,